# How does encasing an egg in flour prevent it from breaking when dropped off of a tall building?

Tags: forces

If you place an egg (raw) in the middle of a tin coffee can which is 1/2 filled with flour, then fill up remaining space of the can with even more flour and drop it from a high building the egg inside remains undamaged.

Can anybody explain to me, why is that? Which forces/energy are/is converted in which way?

Answer (score 0):

to break the egg's shell requires deforming it out of its original shape. By burying the egg in flour, the shock load of hitting the floor is conveyed all the way round the egg shell by the flour (which behaves a little like a liquid and a little like a solid when struck). this prevents the egg shell from being flattened slightly by the shock and thereby prevents it from breaking. the same principle was used years ago when burying a special type of sewer pipe called Orangeburg pipe; it was thin and brittle (made of tar-saturated paper rolled in a tube) and you had to situate it in a trench and completely surround it with crushed gravel which was then covered with dirt. the idea was that the gravel would transmit any load imposed from above uniformly around the circumference of the pipe and clamp it snugly into its round shape, and prevent it from collapsing. It almost worked.

Comment: Will the tin material of the can absorb most of the kinetic energy at the moment of impact or is the kinetic energy converted in friction energy by the flour particles?

Comment: the can will certainly deform and the flour will accomodate that deformation without stressing the eggshell. I do not know how to estimate the energy losses in each step of the process.